# How do display "no results" after async function returns null in angular template?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using an async function to get results from a search query. I like to display the loading status of the search so I do:

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding" *ngIf="results | async as res; else loading">
  <ion-list *ngIf="res; else noRes">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>{{res.title}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>{{res.amenities}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ng-template #noRes>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>No results to display</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ng-template>

  <ion-button [routerLink]="['/home']">Return</ion-button>
</ion-content>
<ng-template #loading>
  <ion-progress-bar type="indeterminate" reversed="true"></ion-progress-bar>
</ng-template>
```

However when the results are null it's stuck on the loading template. `noRes` never fires

Here's the component to the page:

```
export class SearchResultsComponent {
  query: string;
  results: Promise<GetPageResults>;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    search: SearchQueryService
  ) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(async () => {
      if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
        this.query = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.q;
        console.log('Query => ' + this.query);
        this.results = search.amplifySearch(this.query);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When results exist the loading component works as expected and the results are displayed. When there are no results the component is stuck on loading. How can I stop loading when there are simply no results to display?

Comment: Can you tell what format your data is coming in results - res when data is there and when data is not there ?

Comment: Fixed my issue by instead of returning "null" from the service--return an empty object and on the template do "<ion-list *ngIf="res.title; else noRes">"

Comment: try use `*ngIf="res && res.length;else noRes"` (I feel that the response in an empty array, not null).  Another way can be "map" you call so, if return an empty array return null